# How can disable the textbox post back in php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, postback

How can I disable or remove the page post back from textbox?

When I press enter key in textbox the page was post back. I have a button to save the data through ajax function.

```
<form name="test" class="form panel" id="test" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="user" />
  <input type="button" name="save" value="save" onclick="save()"/>
</form>
```

the saving function are working good,the problem is textbox,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an AJAX form then prevent the form from submission:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

## HTML Solution

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

## JS Solution

you can define a keypress handler on the form:

```
document.querySelector('form').onkeypress = checkEnter; 

function checkEnter(e){
 e = e || event;
 var txtArea = /textarea/i.test((e.target || e.srcElement).tagName);
 return txtArea || (e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode || 0) !== 13;
}
```

## jQuery Solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter in a textbox is normal behavior for forms and the user might be confused when it hits enter in the textbox to find that nothing happened.

You could prevent the submit with the following script

```
<form onsubmit="return okToSubmit;"...

var okToSubmit=false;
function save(){
// ... your code
  okToSubmit=true;
// form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only idea is to prevent on enter event for textbox this could work:

```
<form name="test" class="form panel" id="test" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) event.preventDefault();"/>
<input type="button" name="save" value="save" onclick="save()"/>
</form>
```